# SSRS display signature text box on first page only

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, ssrs-2012

On a `SSRS` report I need to display a `signature textbox` at the bottom of the first page only. Something like this:

Page 1.
Tablix (Data retuned from SQL) |
Signature line |
Footer

Page 2.
Tablix (Rest of data retuned from SQL) |
Footer

Page 3.
Tablix (Rest of data retuned from SQL)
 |
Footer

And so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are just adding a box with a label into the footer and you only want that to be visible on the first page?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need the label as part of the body not the footer.  And the label should only display on the first page.

Answer (score 1):

Create the box in the body and make display conditional based on page no

[Access Page number in report body In SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758793/access-page-number-in-report-body-in-ssrs)

Answer (score 1):

Create another Tablix for Signature and set it visibility by expression like below.

Tablix Properties - > Visibility - > SHow or hide based on an expression
 write the expression for hidden as =IIf(Globals!PageName = 1,False,True)

Comment: My report has 2 pages per customer number. My report contains 50 customers so I have 100 pages in total when I export to PDF. If I use the code you provided I will get the Signature only on Page 1 of 100. I need the signature on the first page for every customer number. So I need it to show up on Page 1 Page 3 Page 5 Page 7 etc... Can I set the expression to check if the page number is odd or even?? If it is odd then show the Signature. If it is even then hide it. IS this possible solution?

Comment: I was able to do it using an expression to determine if it was on an odd or even page number. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Shakti. +1