# RDLC Page Footer on First Page Only

Tags: visual-studio, report, rdlc

I made .rdlc report in VS 2013. Report is with multiple pages. I only want to show footer on first page. 
I only selected print on first page in print option of footer properties and left print on last page unchecked, but its showing footer on all pages except the last page.

If report data is of two pages then it shows correctly but problem in more then two pages.

I went through all the posts avaliable on stackoverflow and other sites but no luck.

Any suggestions.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue by hiding the contents of the footer on all pages except first page. Although footer is still taking the space but this is enough for the client as the report is actually a bill in which footer part is bank copy and they only want to stamp on first page.

source: [Access Page number in report body In SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758793/access-page-number-in-report-body-in-ssrs)