# SSRS report - use Gobals in report body

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have spent a lot of time trying to overcome this limitation - using global variables in the report body. Is there any chance of making it work - accessing Globals!PageNumber in the report body?

Thanks

Comment: No SSRS global variables can't be used in the report body.

Comment: You can check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758793/access-page-number-in-report-body-in-ssrs to access-page-number-in-report-body