# How to get reference from header Textfield to Body using SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS reports, where i need to display total pages in the report body.

As with the understanding we cant use globals in the report body, i thought whether we can take a reference from the header total no.of pages text box and display it in the header.

For example:

Header has a text box “textbox1” holding the Globals.!TotalPages and it has total pages of the report.

In the body i have another text box “textbox2” where i need the reference to the textbox1 then i can access the total pages value in the body.

Comment: There is a typo i apologize, updating it here As with the understanding we cant use globals in the report body, i thought whether we can take a reference from the header total no.of pages text box and display it in the BODY*.

For example:

Header has a text box “textbox1” holding the Globals.!TotalPages and it has total pages of the report.

In the body i have another text box “textbox2” where i need the reference to the textbox1 then i can access the total pages value in the body.

Comment: You should edit your question with any corrections or additional information rather than using the comments.

Comment: have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758793/access-page-number-in-report-body-in-ssrs