# Make row occupy space avaiable

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

How can I make a row of a tablix occupy the remaining space of a page?

Things I tried:

- Create a new empty row and adjust its height to occupy the page, but this row has a fixed height meaning if I have more data the table will expand to the next page
- I changed `CanShrink` and `CanGrow` without avail
- Changed the cell height instead of row height it gives the same behavior as before

I'm afraid it won't be possible to do this.

Comment: Can explain why you need to do this? May help with the answer.

Comment: @Jim I need to make the table occuppy the remaing space. I'll add a screenshot

Comment: @Jim Visual (aesthetic) reasons

Comment: I searched for the same, but did not find any solution. please let me know if you find any perfect match solution... @Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Only if the report takes only one page**

One way to do this is to separate the totals into a different table and use rectangles to simulate the columns.

[image]

**Found a workaround that works for multiple pages (almost)**

- Place the 1st table contents inside a rectangle
- Enable Add a page break after, in the rectangle properties
- Place the totals outside the rectangle
- keep using rectangles to simulate do columns (those rectangles need to be inside the rectangle that breaks the page
- Done

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have a row fill up the remainder of the page you should set each(?) [row to break on a new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257276/how-to-create-a-report-with-sections-and-page-breaks-using-ssrs).

Comment: I've added a link to the answer.

Comment: I don't want to have a row in each page that wastes to much paper.

Comment: OK, so your question is really "How do I get the totals to appear at the bottom of the page"? I think? Might be worth amending?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866318/ssrs-reports-force-table-to-expand-to-bottom-of-page